# Why does my github url permission got denied when I'm pushing it?

Tags: git

When I was going to push my works to the git hub the git bash terminal said this.

> "Lenovo@SkiWalker MINGW64 /d/Programming/Github Rep/CSS-Grid-Demo (master)
>   $ git push
>   remote: Permission to Skywalker-official/CSS-Grid-Demo.git denied to siara989.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Skywalker-official/CSS-Grid-Demo.git                                                                                                                /': The requested URL returned error: 403" 
>   <

Skywalker-official - this is my Git hub username.

siara989 - this is a username of my friend

Recently I logged into her account by using my laptop and pushed some works to her git hub account. after that I'm facing to this situation. I'm a beginner still. Therefor I don't know about many commands in git. So could you please tell me how to avoid this and continue pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the credentials in git. If you are using windows the easiest way to do this is to go to credential manager, windows credentials, and then change the ones currently set in git. You have to do this everytime you change your username or password otherwise git will try pushing with old information and it will fail with the same error message you get above.

If you're on mac I'd recommend this article detailing the steps to take:

https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Comment: I see `MINGW64` and `d:\programming` in the question so it's not MacOS.

Comment: @phd I figured I'd include it to be helpful in case anyone stumbles upon this question who is on mac